# What is an alternative to hook_node_view()?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, panels

When a node is rendered in a panel pane, `hook_node_view()` is not invoked. (I use [Panels 7.x-3.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels/releases/7.x-3.4).) Is there any alternative to change rendered node content in any other hook?

I have tried  with `hook_ctools_render_alter()`, but the HTML output of the node is presented as one large string. I need to change node content in one particular field, so I need to access a `$node` variable as an array, as it happens with `hook_node_view()`. I need to execute custom PHP for changing the output of one of the fields.

Comment: Perhaps [`hook_panels_pane_content_alter`](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/panels/panels%21panels.api.php/function/hook_panels_pane_content_alter/7.x) or [`hook_panels_pane_prerender`](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/panels/panels%21panels.api.php/function/hook_panels_pane_prerender/7.x) or [`hook_panels_pre_render`](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/panels/panels%21panels.api.php/function/hook_panels_pre_render/7.x)

Comment: hook_panels_pane_content_alter - contains HTML output as a string in $content variable, so I cannot use it as an array before rendering

Comment: hook_panels_pane_prerender - contains some configuration parameters of pane, but I don't see possibility to change part of content there

Comment: hook_panels_pre_render  - I don't see as option too, it is higher level of settings from whole display and panel

Answer (score 0):

If you are just editing one field you can use [`template_preprocess_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7.x), [`hook_field_display_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_alter/7.x), or [`hook_field_display_ENTITY_TYPE_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_ENTITY_TYPE_alter/7.x). Those should also fire in other contexts if you use that field outside the panel pane in the future (which may be a good or bad side-effect depending on your context).